# Writing c++ output into xlsx file

Tags: c++, xlsx

I have a certain function in my c++ code which compares 2 .bmp files( a reference file is compared with almost 100 files in another directory one at a time), bit by bit and reports the bit errors properly when run a in terminal window. The function that does that is as follows :

```
 void getBitErrors(char *filename, char *dirName, int height, int width){

DIR *dir;
struct dirent *ent;
//char *f = "";
    dir = opendir (dirName);
if (dir != NULL) {
    /* print all the files and directories within directory */
    while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
        if(strcmp(ent->d_name,".") && strcmp(ent->d_name,".."))
        {
              char f[255]="";
          strcat(f,dirName);
          strcat(f,ent->d_name);    
              printf ("reading image file %s\n", f);
          cout<<"Bit Error "<<getBitError(filename,f,height,width)<<endl;
        }
       }
       closedir (dir);
 } 
else {
perror ("");
    }
}
```

I wish to have a function in my code that writes the 100 respective comparison values into an xlsx/obs file .(As opposed to having the output displayed by std::cout in a terminal window.) I have looked into 2 different options .
1) Self explanatory libXL which is a paid library and I dont really have a $199 to pay for this library.
2) SimpleXlsx which is slightly hazy. 
I would be awfully obliged if someone were to explain to me how i could go about achieving my result. 
OS : Linux Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick.

Comment: If you have Excel, you can provide CSV output from your program and convert CSV to xlsx using Excel itself. It is not what you are asking for but it is the simpliest way to convert some program output to Excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you look at the `.csv` (comma Separated Values) format. You can get a spreadsheet like result with that with much less complexity.

Comment: Yeah. That was also one of the options I was looking at and it does seem easy as well. The only problem is that one of the requirements is that the output should be an xlsx file.

Comment: Creating a native xlsx file is not easy. An alternative might be to save as a csv file, open the file with Excel and save it as .xlsx. If you don't like to do it manually, you can automate the conversion by using Excel Interop libraries.